# XSLT best practices for handling templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm writing an xslt for a rather complex xml. The xml has several child nodes, and many of them has many child nodes.

Each child element has its own template. I thought about putting the templates that are logically related on each other to a separate file, and import them.

Is this a good practice in xslt, should I have a really long xslt instead, or is there a better solution to make an easily maintanable xslt file?

Thank you.

Comment: "Rather complex" is rather subjective, if you forgive the pun. The bottom line is: as soon as the stylesheet is too long for you, the developer, that's when you should _modularize_ the code. Let me rephrase your question: _Should an XSLT stylesheet have a reasonable size and import the rest - or not?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use xsl:import if you want the templates you are importing to have a lower precedence (i.e be overridable) than the templates that are in the main stylesheet.

If you just want to cluster logically related templates in a separate stylesheet use xsl:include  to incorporate them into your stylesheet.

I don't think the length of the stylesheet matters as long as it is entirely composed of templates that can be directly traced to the input document. If I can look at a given node in the input and hone straight in on the template that will process it, that in itself is sufficient modularisation and  I personally wouldn't worry about fragmenting the stylesheet further. If you do fragment it you'll have to figure out which stylesheet to look at for the template you are interested in.

There may be version control considerations i.e you may wish your version control to track just the fragment that was changed rather than the entire stylesheet. Other than that subject to the caveat I mentioned it's a matter of choice. However if the code would be reusable in other stylesheets then that changes everything and  you should definitely fragment it.

If you are going to fragment the stylesheet you may wish to have a naming scheme that differentiates stylesheets that are meant to be stand-alone from those that are meant to be included. You may also want to have a convention for naming imported stylesheets.

Make sure you understand the difference between xsl:import and xsl:include and don't use import for things you can include.